# A Conjecture in Low-Dimensional Topology.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

**Context**

I looked through a book called "Problems in Low-Dimensional Topology," where Rob Kirby lists a set of problems. He provides a list of problems, states their conjectures, and describes any progress on the problems. The book was published in 1995, so I don't know if some of the problems that Kirby stated are still open or proven. 
There is one problem that stood out for me.

> **Problem 1.8 (Stallings)**
> Suppose $\beta$ is a word in the generators $\sigma_1 , . . . , \sigma_{n−1}$ and their inverses in the braid group $B_n$. If the length of $\beta$ is minimal over all words representing the same element of $B_n$, call β minimal.

> **Conjecture:** If the last letter of a minimal word $\beta$ is $\sigma_i^\epsilon$, then the word $\beta\sigma_i$ is again minimal $(\epsilon = \pm1)$.

**Question**
My first question is a matter of understanding the statement. What does it mean to be minimal? Is it saying that for a word $\beta$ with a last letter of $\sigma_i^\epsilon$ and an inverse in the braid group, if it's in its reduced form representing the same element of $B_n$ (which doesn't make sense because how can a reduced word represent the same element of a group?) then $\sigma_i$ is again minimal? If $\epsilon=-1$, then how can $\beta\sigma_i$ represent the same element of the group as well? My misunderstanding is with the term *minimal*.

My second question is about the status of the conjecture. Kirby states that this is still an open problem. Has this conjecture been proven since then? I tried to look for stalling conjectures on the internet, but I couldn't find a webpage that talks about this problem. Is there a different name for this conjecture?

Comment: The definition is unambiguous: $\beta$ is minimal means it is length-minimal among all words in the $\sigma_i$ defining the same element. If $\beta$ is of the form $\beta = \tilde{\beta} \sigma_i^\epsilon$ for $\tilde{\beta}$ a word in the $\sigma_i$, then the conjecture states that $\beta \sigma_i$ is minimal _for the element it represents_, not the one $\beta$ represents.

Comment: Ow I see, I understood the definition the same way but I misinterpreted the problem as both minimal words describing the same element. Thank you!

Comment: I also suspect the second part of the question might fare better over on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) since it's about (relatively) recent research.

Comment: Cross-postning of the status question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/465848/4177